# Автоматическое заполнение формы в Django Template

Tags: python, forms, шаблоны, django

Добрый день.

Есть форма пользовательского профиля.
При выводе на экран ее надо заполнить данными текущего пользователя.
Как это можно сделать?

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_pic/', blank=True, verbose_name='аватар')
    phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, verbose_name=u'контактный телефон')

class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=u'Имя', max_length=30, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=u'Фамилия', max_length=30, required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(label=u'Пароль', widget=forms.PasswordInput, min_length=4, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(label=u'E-mail', required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(label=u'Контактный телефон', max_length=10, required=True)
    img = forms.ImageField(label=u'Ваш автар или логотип', required=False)

@render_to('profile.html')
def edit_profile(request):
    form = LoginForm()

 {{ form_profile.as_p }}
```

Хочется заполнять форму автоматически (руками в шаблоне чтобы особо ничего не расписывать). 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

На сколько я понял, Вам необходмо воспользоваться наследованием форм от моделей [документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/). Используя правильное наследование формы от модели, вы сможете автоматически заполнять форму данными из уже существуещего обьекта:

```
form = ProfileForm(instance=user)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Пробежался по тексту. Еще не пробовал, но сразу имею вопрос: как интересно сделать наследование формы от модели User? Мне ведь надо, чтобы форма Profile содержала поля User + Profile.

Comment: Могу посоветовать в таком случае часть данных инициализировать наследованием от объекта, а другую часть от данных выбранных из объекта другого типа, что то вроде: form = SomeForm(instance=obj, initial=data)

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже сделал по совету ниже, но Ваш красивый вариант обязательно попробую на днях

Comment: Он не только красивей, он даже лучше и проще, ну и времени уходит меньше. Если будете начинать новый проект, то пробуйте формы делать через ModelForm.
Если ответ решен, то закрывайте его.

Answer (score 4):

Например можно передать в форму словарь

```
    data = {'first_name': 'Ivan', 'last_name': 'Ivanov', 'email': 'a@b.ru'}
    form = ProfileForm(data)
```

Попробуйте еще

```
user = Profile.objects.get(user=self)
form = ProfileForm(user)
```

могу сильно ошибаться, т.к. не помню уже как можно узнать свой профайл

Comment: Словарь передается и это уже хорошо. А при попытке form = ProfileForm(user) получаю ошибку:

TemplateSyntaxError at /profile/
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'User' object has no attribute 'get'

на строке: {{ form_profile.as_p }}

То есть, либо руками во вьюхе, либо ими же в шаблоне :)

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял, вы собираетесь некоторые поля формы заполнить темы, что записаны у Django User Model обьекта.

1. Если форма в полном виде должна отображаться на сайте, но с заполнеными полями, с возможностью их редактировать:

- Вам следует залезть в процесс представления, изъять у self.request.user необходимые данные и передать в любом виде к шаблону, а там влезть в процесс отображения формы и передать забранные данные

2. Если поля не должны отображаться в форме, но должны иметь значение, при валидации:

- Вам следует изучить формы подробнее, и как можно реализовать подобие HiddenField как у serializer в DRF, эту задачу я оставлю на Вас. Послез залезть в процесс валидации, или в любую точку, в которой форме не сохранилась, и передать дату с нужными данными.

Comment: вы всерьез пытаетесь обращаться к человеку, кто задал вопрос более 10 лет назад?

Comment: Вижу вопрос, не вижу препядствий

Comment: "Вам следует залезть в процесс представления" - 10 лет спустя? Выглядит забавно. Сам ответ для базы знаний подходит.